# My password is 2

Tags: rhyme, password

Evil mastermind PhD Evil, is trying to destroy the north pole. In order to foil his plan you need to log on to his computer. Alas you don't know the password, thankfully PhD Evil thinks he is too clever. So he left a puzzle to solve his password.

> My password is 2
>   It is ten too.
>   My password is seven letters long
>   four letters is also not wrong
>
> It is fair to say that it is none
>   but that could  be off by one
>   If you think my password is a single hole,
>   I will blow up the north Pole!

Your partner says, I don't really care the north pole is fake. But you persevere for Santa's sake.

What is the password?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **onezero** (**10** or **ten**)

My password is 2

> 10 in binary is 2

It is ten too.

> 10 in base ten is 10

My password is seven letters long

> "onezero" is seven letters long

four letters is also not wrong

> (maybe) 10 in Spanish is diez, four letters
>
>  or (credit to Niktheslik)
>
>  One zero could be interpreted as just "zero" which has 4 letters

It is fair to say that is is none

but that could be off by one

> 0 is none, but it is missing the 1 in front of it

If you think my password is a single hole,

I will blow up the north Pole!

> 0 (single hole) is the wrong password

Comment: A better explanation for four letters is also not wrong: zero is 1 zero, as in a singular zero. So one zero is, in that sense, equivalent to just zero as a zero is 1 zero.

Comment: @Niktheslik Perhaps but in that case the password is the string "onezero", which it might be, I'll edit my answer to include it

Comment: I like this solution. About the "four letters is also not wrong" explanation, it could be: "Deca", which is a metric unit prefix indicating ten multiples of the unit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

Comment: @Axle onezero is indeed the intended solution. Well done.

Comment: I think four letters is 'onez'.